# Active admin not working in production mode

Tags: activeadmin

I am using a active admin gem in my rails application

in development mode active admin working properly

but when I try to access it in a production mode it gives me that error

```
ror@techi-ror:~/Desktop/quiz$ rails s -e production
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 4.2.1 application starting in production on http://localhost:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Exiting
/home/ror/Desktop/quiz/config/initializers/active_admin.rb:1:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant ActiveAdmin (NameError)
    from /home/ror/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:652:in `block in load_config_initializer'
    from /home/ror/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `instrument'
    from /home/ror/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:651:in `load_config_initializer'
    from /home/ror/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:616:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
    from /home/ror/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:615:in `each'
    from /home/ror/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:615:in `block in <class:Engine>'
    from /home/ror/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
    from /home/ror/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
    from /home/ror/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
    from /home/ror/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:226:in `block in tsort_each'
    from /home/ror/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:348:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /home/ror/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:420:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /home/ror/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:429:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /home/ror/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:419:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /home/ror/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `each'
    from /home/ror/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `tsort_each_child'
    from /home/ror/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:413:in `call'
    from /home/ror/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:413:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /home/ror/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:347:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /home/ror/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each'
    from /home/ror/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `call'
    from /home/ror/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /home/ror/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:224:in `tsort_each'
    from /home/ror/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:203:in `tsort_each'
    from /home/ror/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
    from /home/ror/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
    from /home/ror/Desktop/quiz/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/ror/Desktop/quiz/config.ru:3:in `require'
    from /home/ror/Desktop/quiz/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
    from /home/ror/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
    from /home/ror/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
    from /home/ror/Desktop/quiz/config.ru:in `new'
    from /home/ror/Desktop/quiz/config.ru:in `<main>'
    from /home/ror/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
    from /home/ror/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
    from /home/ror/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
    from /home/ror/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:299:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
    from /home/ror/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:208:in `app'
    from /home/ror/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:61:in `app'
    from /home/ror/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:336:in `wrapped_app'
    from /home/ror/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:272:in `start'
    from /home/ror/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:80:in `start'
    from /home/ror/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:80:in `block in server'
    from /home/ror/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
    from /home/ror/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
    from /home/ror/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
    from /home/ror/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/ror/Desktop/quiz/bin/rails:8:in `require'
    from /home/ror/Desktop/quiz/bin/rails:8:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/ror/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
    from /home/ror/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
    from /home/ror/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
    from /home/ror/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/client.rb:26:in `run'
    from /home/ror/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/spring-1.3.6/bin/spring:48:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/ror/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `load'
    from /home/ror/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/ror/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /home/ror/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /home/ror/Desktop/quiz/bin/spring:13:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:3:in `load'
    from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
```

I Don't know how to fix this problem please help me for fixing this issue

---

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.2.1'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
#gem 'sqlite3'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
 gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password

# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug'

  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'

  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'devise'
  gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails'
  gem 'mysql2'
  gem "bootstrap-sass-rails"     
  gem 'jquery-turbolinks'
  gem 'activeadmin', github: 'activeadmin'
  gem 'activerecord-session_store', github: 'rails/activerecord-session_store'
  gem 'pry'

    end
```

thats my gem file

Answer (score 1):

You need to a the `activeadmin` to you complete gemfile not only to the development/test group